# JSDoc resolve unresolved variable

Tags: javascript, dojo, webstorm, jsdoc

I use Dojo, and some page widgets are defined outside of code, in HTML template. How can I say to JSDoc that some `this` fields are really defined?

SomePage.js

```
define([ "dojo/dom", "dojo/on", "dojo/_base/lang" ],
   function(dom, on, lang) {

      return {        
            init: function(){    
                on(this._myButton, "click", lang.hitch(this, this._foo));
            },

            foo: function(){
                //some code here
            }
      }            
   }
});
```

SomePage.html

```
<div>
    <div class="Button" data-dojo-attach-point="_myButton">
        Click me!
    </div>
</div>
```

In this sample, JSDoc warns me that `this._myButton` is unresolved. It's really undefined in visible scope, but in fact it is guaranteed to be defined by Dojo via `data-dojo-attach-point`. How can I override JSDoc and say him that `this._myButton` is defined for current module? (Webstorm IDE is used)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, and currently it's "solved" not automatically, but through style/discipline. I don't have the code in front of me, but at work we're making widgets something like this:

```
define([
        "dojo/declare", 
        "dojo/dom",
        "dojo/on",
        "dojo/_base/lang",
        "dijit/_WidgetBase",
        "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
        "dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin",
        "dojo/text!./templates/myTemplate.html"
        "dijit/form/Button" // Instantiated in template
], function(declare, dom, on, lang, _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin, template) {         
        return declare([_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, WidgetsInTemplateMixin],{        
            templateString:template,    


            // Attachpoints
            _myButtonWidget:null,
            _someThingyNode:null,

            init: function(){    
                on(this._myButtonWidget, "click", lang.hitch(this, this._foo));
            },
            foo: function(){
                //some code here
            }
        });            
});
```

With a `myTemplate.html` like:

```
<div>
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" data-dojo-attach-point="_myButton">
        Click me!
    </div>
    <div data-dojo-attach-point="someThingyNode"><!-- Not a widget--></div>
</div>
```

The main takeaway should be that you're making the property without waiting for Dojo to make it at runtime. As a personal convention, attached dijits end in "Widget" and any "vanilla" attachpoints are named "Node".

Benefits:

1. It makes your IDE happy so it doesn't pop up unnecessary warnings
2. It makes your IDE able to offer code-completion
3. It notifies whomever is reading the `.js` file that the attachpoints exist
4. Especially with a lot of attachpoints, you don't have to keep referring to the `.html` template to figure out whether you're dealing with a sub-widget versus a vanilla DOM node.

Comment: This will work for pageViews. I can also add that if you are creating your own widget using `declare`, you can implicitly define `this._myButtonWidget` in constructor

Comment: "For PageViews"? I think it's a little cleaner if it isn't in the `constructor()` method, since it makes it look *slightly* more like a placeholder (which it is) than a value which is being assigned for later. Maybe it's just spillover style preference from PHP/Java.

Comment: If you use `declare` function, there is a difference between something defined in constructor or outside. Every reference defined outside is shared between all object instances (like 'static' in Java). That's why I prefer to keep definition inside, if possible

Comment: I avoid that by only setting the "outside" definitions to `null`, but I suppose somebody not familiar with the code could put in something like `[]` by accident.